# SSRS 2016 List View Search

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

Since we've installed SSRS 2016 SP1, when using the search box, the links that are generated for the report contain the search term as a query string for the report, which is causing them to error.

This causes the following error:

An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'filter' that is not defined in this report. (rsUnknownReportParameter)
Is this a config issue, or is there a bug with SP1? It doesn't seem to do this on the Tile View, only the List View.

Comment: Chris we are experiencing the same thing, looks like its only when searching using the new list view.

Comment: Glad to hear at least someone else is having the same issue! Seems to be a few bugs have snuck into the latest releases of SSRS.

Comment: CU1 has been released, cant see mention of this but will give it a go and see if its fixed

Comment: The problem also happens in SQL 2016 SP1 CU1. I have posted a bug report at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3127601

Comment: I've voted for this - thanks for posting it to Connect.